# WiFi programming in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

What is ScanResult.capabilities? Since I don't have a device, I don't know the format of it.

How do you connect to a specific API? I have looked through the API documentation but found no method to implement the function. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I tried in vain to just browse up the relevant code, knowing that the Android platform is open source, but failed. However, it should still be possible if you're willing to [follow the guide](http://source.android.com/download) on how to get the source.

Of course, reading the source to see how they generate that particular string might well result in your app being "locked" against a particular implementation, I saw indications that they intend to change it from a string into something a bit more structured, later.